How to convert the premium file share to premium block blob storage account or standard general purpose v2 storage account?
I have created the Premium File Storage Kind of Storage Account in the Azure.

I want to convert it to Standard General Purpose V2 Account which has all items such as Blob Storage, Tables, file Storage, and queue service.
I cannot see any option to convert it.

It is not possible to convert a Premium File Storage to Standard General Purpose V2 account. What you have to do is create a new account and migrate data from your premium account to standard account.
From the documentation link

